Playwright - issue with the footer template parsing
Playwright (Python) save a page as PDF function works fine when there's no customisation in the header or footer. However, when I try to introduce a custom footer, the values don't seem to get injected appropriately.
Example code:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def generate_pdf_with_page_numbers():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()

        # Navigate to the desired page
        page.goto('https://example.com')

        # Generate PDF with page numbers in the footer
        pdf = page.pdf(
            path="output.pdf",
            format="A4",
            display_header_footer=True,
            footer_template="""
                <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 10px;">
                    Page {{pageNumber}} of {{totalPages}}
                </div>
            """,
            margin={"top": "40px", "bottom": "40px"}
        )

        browser.close()

# Run the function to generate the PDF
generate_pdf_with_page_numbers()


I was expecting:
Page 1 of 1

But actually I get:
Page {{pageNumber}} of {{totalPages}}

Do you see any issue with this code?

I tried with {totalPages} as well, because I felt incorrect to use {{}} in Python, yet with no luck.

Thanks for your prompt response. Much appreciated. However I already tried without luck. Good news is I just now found the result. But it actually doesn't yet make sense to me. It requires you to have the class name to be used. The class name is the parameter of the attribute (page number, url, timestamp etc). For instance, for above case, it shoule be Page <span class="pageNumber"></span> of <span class="totalPages"></span>. That prints out Page 1 of 1 now. It looks like the template use JS parsing, instead of Python wrapper.

From the Playwright docs, header_template (which has the same format as footer_template) provides a number of magic class names you can use to inject certain pieces of data into the page:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright # 1.44.0


def generate_pdf_with_page_numbers():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        context = browser.new_context()
        page = context.new_page()
        page.goto("https://example.com")
        pdf = page.pdf(
            path="output.pdf",
            format="A4",
            display_header_footer=True,
            footer_template="""
                <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 10px;">
                    Page <span class="pageNumber"></span> of
                    <span class="totalPages"></span>
                    <div class="title"></div>
                    <div class="url"></div>
                    <div class="date"></div>
                </div>
            """,
            margin={"top": "40px", "bottom": "40px"}
        )
        browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate_pdf_with_page_numbers()

Run the code, open output.pdf and observe the title, date, URL and pages injected into the footer.
